# Pivot camera around object on drag

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, camera, drag

In my three.js scene I have an object with the `{x: 0, y:0 z:-150}`. My camera has a position of  `{x:0, y:0, z:75);`. What I want is that the user can drag the camera around the object, so that the user keeps looking at the object.

[image]

The camera needs to follow the given circle stroke on a drag to the left or to the right.

I tried to use `OrbitControls` and a `pivotPoint` to get this result:

```
const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.update();
         
object.position.set(0, 0, -150);
pivotPoint = new THREE.Object3D();
object.add(pivotPoint);

camera.position.set(0, 0, 75);
camera.lookAt(object.position);
```

The problem I have now is that the camera rotates around itself and not around the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like so:

```js
camera.position.set(0, 0, 75);

object.position.set(0, 0, -150);

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.target.copy(object.position);
controls.update();
```

The idea of the above code is to make use of the [target](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.target) property of `OrbitControls` which represents the focus point. There is no need to manually call `lookAt()` on the camera object.